# When using @mock.patch, does it still evaluate the function arguments?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I've been using the `@mock.patch` decorator from the unittest library.

```
@mock.patch("path.to.process.process", return_value=0)
def unit_test_func(.....):
  # call stuff and eventually in the chain of calls the function process gets called
```

and the function `process` is:

```
def process(obj.url):
  ....
```

Since I put a patch for `process`, would it still try to evaluate `obj.url`? That appears to be what's going on in my code, and I'm wondering how I can eliminate any argument evaluations using `@mock.patch`?

Comment: With that code, you'll get a type error, because the value `0` isn't callable. `def process(obj.url) ->:` is a syntax error; the *parameter* has to be a name, not an expression. An attempt to *call* `process(obj.url)` with some appropriate value `obj` that has an attribute will fail with the aforementioned type error.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, I edited the OP with the corrections

Comment: That's still an invalid function definition. Are you talking about the original function, or a *call* to the function?

Comment: @chepner `unit_test_func` calls a series of functions and eventually those functions that it calls trickles down to `process`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, realize that a patch is nothing more than an object that represents the idea of replacing the value of a name with a new value. When you first create the patch, nothing happens. When you call the patch's `start` method, the reassignment takes place. When you call the patch's `stop` method, the original value is restores.

You can patch a name with *any* value you like, simply by providing it:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> x = 3
>>> p = patch('__main__.x', 5)p.
>>> x
3
>>> p.start()
5
>>> x
5
>>> p.stop()
False
>>> x
3
```

If you do't provide a new value, `patch` creates a new instance of `MagicMock` instead. Keyword arguments to be passed to `MagicMock` (like `return_value`) can be passed to `patch` instead.

```
>>> p = patch('__main__.x', return_value=6)
>>> p.start()
<MagicMock name='x' id='4562276992'>
>>> x()
6
>>> p.stop()
False
>>> x
3
```

When you use an instance of `patch` as a decorator, it creates a new function that wraps the call of the original between calls to the patch's `start` and `stop` method, as well as ensuring the new value is passed to the original function as an argument.

---

The `MagicMock` itself is callable just like any other function: its argument(s) are evaluated, then passed to the `MagicMock`'s `__call__` method. The "magic" here is not that the function call is "replaced" with the value of `return_value`, but that `MagicMock.__call__` is defined to *use* the value of the `return_value` object as the return value. A simple argument with a side effect can demonstrate this:

```
>>> p.start()
<MagicMock name='x' id='4570368128'>
>>> x(print("foo"))
foo
6
```

The `MagicMock`'s `__call__` method *ignores* the `None` value produced by the call to `print`, but you can still see that `print("foo")` was in fact called and wrote `foo` to standard output before `x` returns the value `6`.